# Trying to create project for specific product id laravel-8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

1. A user have many products and product have own id
   2)And A product have many projects
   I have trouble to make ProjectController
   Note: if you need more details you can ask.
   This is my user model user.php

```
public function Products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product');

    }

    public function Project(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Project');
    }
```

This is my Product model product.php

```
public function User(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function Project(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Project');
    }
```

This is my project model project.php

```
public function User(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function Product(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
```

Here product table have user_id as forignId and project table have user_id and product_id as forign key
This is project table project.php

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger ('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('product_id')->nullable();
```

This is here I have troubles in ProjectController.php

```
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // $projects = Project::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->latest()->paginate(20);
        $projects = Project::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->where('product_id')->latest()->paginate(20);



        return view('projects.index', compact('projects'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('projects.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'chapter_name' => 'required',
            'sub_section_name' => 'required',
            'title_1' => 'required',
            'description_1' => 'required',
            'image_1' => 'required',
            'image_2' => 'required',
            'image_3' => 'required',
            'title_2' => 'required',
            'description_2' => 'required',
            'title_3' => 'required',
            'description_3' => 'required',
            'video_1' => 'required',
            'video_2' => 'required',
            'video_3' => 'required',
        ]);

        // $input = $request->all();
        $input['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
        $input['product_id'] = $id;

        Project::create($input);

        return redirect()->route('project.index')
                        ->with('success','Product created successfully.');

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Project $project)
    {
        // $category = $project->category;
        return view('projects.show', compact('project'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Project $project)
    {
        return view('projects.edit', compact('project'));
    }
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
        // $user_id =  Auth::user()->id ;

        $request->validate([
            'chapter_name' => 'required',
            'sub_section_name' => 'required',
            'title_1' => 'required',
            'description_1' => 'required',
            'image_1' => 'required',
            'image_2' => 'required',
            'image_3' => 'required',
            'title_2' => 'required',
            'description_2' => 'required',
            'title_3' => 'required',
            'description_3' => 'required',
            'video_1' => 'required',
            'video_2' => 'required',
            'video_3' => 'required',
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        $project->update($input);

        return redirect()->route('project.index')
                        ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
    }
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Project $project)
    {
        $project->delete();

        return redirect()->route('projects.index')
            ->with('success', 'Project deleted successfully');
    }

    public function importProject()
    {
        Excel::import(new ProjectsImport, request()->file('file'));

        return back()->with('success','Project created successfully.');
    }

    public function export()
    {
        return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'projects.xlsx');
    }
}
```

This is user table user.php

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
            $table->text('profile_photo_path')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

This is products table products.php

```
 Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('detail');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('logo');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

This is project table project.php

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('chapter_name', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('sub_section_name', 500)->nullable();
            $table->string('title_1', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('description_1', 5000)->nullable();
            $table->string('image_1', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('image_2', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('image_3', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('title_2', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('description_2', 5000)->nullable();
            $table->string('title_3', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('description_3', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('video_1', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('video_2', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('video_3', 255)->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger ('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            // $table->foreignId('product_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
        });
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Relationships method names should not be `get{Whatever}`, but rather simply `{whatever}`, like `public function products()` or `public function product()` instead of `public function getProducts()` and `public function getProduct()`. That way, Laravel can auto-link them based off your Models.

Comment: I didn`t understand, sorry I am not that much expert i have just started at laravel

Comment: @AbdullahAlShahed , what isn't working?. Please, be specific.

Comment: @AbdullahAlShahed , You say _"A user has many products "_ but then go ahead to make a connection between a _User_ and _Projects_ in both the `User` and `Project` models. Does that mean _A user has many products and projects_?

Comment: now i have this Undefined array key "id" error in my projectImport.php. see my edition this id should be ptoduct id

Comment: @AbdullahAlShahed , [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67876570/edit) and show us the error you're referring to.

Comment: Undefined array key "id" in projectImport.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233482/discussion-between-abdullah-al-shahed-and-steven7mwesigwa).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67882176/undefined-array-key-id-in-laravel-8

Answer (score 0):

Below are 2 possible causes of your error.

1. The uploaded file `request()->file('file')` lucks a column with header name `id`.

If this is the case you may wish to perform some sort of header validation during the import process. i.e:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Project;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class ProjectsImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow
{
    use Importable;

    private const HEADING_NAMES = [
        'chapter_name',
        'sub_section_name',
        'title_1',
        'description_1',
        'image_1',
        'image_2',
        'image_3',
        'title_2',
        'description_2',
        'title_3',
        'description_3',
        'video_1',
        'video_2',
        'video_3',
        'id'
    ];

    private const HEADING_ROW = 0;

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {

        if (
            (count($columnHeadings = array_keys($rows[self::HEADING_ROW])) == count(self::HEADING_NAMES))
            && (array_diff($columnHeadings, self::HEADING_NAMES) === array_diff(self::HEADING_NAMES, $columnHeadings))
        ) {
            redirect()
                ->back()
                ->withErrors([
                    "import" => "Incorrect excel sheet headers."
                        . " "
                        . "Expected:"
                        . " " . json_encode(self::HEADING_NAMES)
                ]);
        }

        // If validation fails, it won't reach the next statement.

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            Project::create([
                'chapter_name' => $row['chapter_name'],
                // ...
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return self::HEADING_ROW;
    }
}
```

2. You're using *header names* to access the data yet by default `$row` indexes are used instead. i.e: `$row[0]` instead of `$row['chapter_name']`.

If this is the case you may wish to implement the `WithHeadingRow` concern.

[Laravel Excel | Heading Row](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/heading-row.html#heading-row)

> In case your file contains a heading row (a row in which each cells
> indicates the purpose of that column) and you want to use those names
> as array keys of each row, you can implement the `WithHeadingRow`
> concern.

i.e:

```php
<?php
use App\Models\Project;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class ProjectsImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Project([
            'chapter_name' => $row['chapter_name'],
            // ...
        ]);
    }
}
```

### Addendum

If the  uploaded file doesn't have the actual `'product_id'`s but instead has the *product names*, you could perform some sort of preprocessing to replace product names with their respective `'product_id'`s.

In addition, you could use some *row validation* to ensure that the *`product names`* exist in the database.

A. Validate product names making sure that they exist.

[Laravel Excel | Row Validation without ToModel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html#row-validation-without-tomodel)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Project;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class ProjectsImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow
{
    use Importable;

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        Validator::make($rows->toArray(), [
            // Table Name: 'products'. Table Column Name: 'name'. Excel Sheet Header Name: 'product_name'.
            '*.product_name' => ['required', 'exists:products,name'],
        ])->validate();

        // If validation fails, it won't reach the next statement.

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            Project::create([

                'chapter_name' => $row['chapter_name'],
                // ...
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

B. *Perform some sort of preprocessing to replace product names with their respective 'product_id's*

[Laravel Excel | Mapping rows](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.0/exports/mapping.html#mapping-rows)

> By adding `WithMapping` you map the data that needs to be added as
> row. This way you have control over the actual source for each column.

i.e:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Project;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;

class ProjectsImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow, WithMapping
{
    use Importable;

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {

        Validator::make($rows->toArray(), [
            '*.chapter_name' => 'required',
            '*.sub_section_name' => 'required',
            '*.title_1' => 'required',
            '*.description_1' => 'required',
            '*.image_1' => 'required',
            '*.image_2' => 'required',
            '*.image_3' => 'required',
            '*.title_2' => 'required',
            '*.description_2' => 'required',
            '*.title_3' => 'required',
            '*.description_3' => 'required',
            '*.video_1' => 'required',
            '*.video_2' => 'required',
            '*.video_3' => 'required',
            '*.product_name' => ['required', 'exists:products,name'],
            '*.product_id' => ['required', 'numeric', 'exists:products,id'],
        ])->validate();

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            Project::create([

                'chapter_name' => $row['chapter_name'],
                'product_id' => $row['product_id']
                // ...
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function map($row): array
    {
        $mappedRow = $row;

        $mappedRow['product_id'] = (isset($row['product_name'])
            && ($product = Product::firstWhere('name', $row['product_name'])))
            ? $product->id
            : null;

        return $mappedRow;

        // From this point, your rules() and model() functions can access the 'product_id'
    }
}
```

#### Addendum 2

It appears that your second `where` clause in `index` method is lucking (`ProjectController`).

```php
    // ...
    public function index()
    {
        // $projects = Project::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->latest()->paginate(20);
        $projects = Project::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->where('product_id')->latest()->paginate(20); ❌

        return view('projects.index', compact('projects'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
   // ...
```

A `where` clause [requires at least 2 parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#building-queries). One `'product_id'` parameter is passed for your case.

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `projects` (`chapter_name`, `sub_section_name`, `title_1`, `description_1`, `image_1`, `image_2`, `image_3`, `title_2`, `description_2`, `title_3`, `description_3`, `video_1`, `video_2`, `video_3`, `user_id`, `product_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (chapter 1, sub 1, titel 1, Desp 1, Img 1, img 2, img 3, Ti 2, Des 2, ti3, des 3, v1, vdo2, vdo3, 1, ?, 2021-06-08 10:19:01, 2021-06-08 10:19:01)) 
This is error now I have added last block of code

Comment: @AbdullahAlShahed , It's because your `projects` table enforces that `product_id` must be supplied. Check my edited answer ([Edit 1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67885069/timeline#history_f4126217-2678-4ef7-8fa8-3efbe839c2df) & [Edit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67885069/timeline#history_74393c63-e7d4-45fa-bc85-85963c16d8c7)) I've just added validation rules to make sure that a `validation error` is displayed on the frontend if any of the fields are _null (empty)_.

Comment: @AbdullahAlShahed, Note that the last implementation assumes that you have an _Excel Sheet column_ with a _header name_ called `product_name`.

Comment: Thanks ProjectImport.php file problem is solved but when i upload excel file its upload nothing form excel file in my database. Are there is any problem in ProjectController

Comment: @AbdullahAlShahed, That's strange. Since I added the [Importable trait](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/importables.html) , could you try using that instead of using the `Excel::import(...)` Facade. i.e: `(new ProjectsImport)->import(request()->file('file'));` in your `importProject` method?. Check your `projects` database table if new entries were added.

Comment: @AbdullahAlShahed , Could you share how your table schema looks like. i.e `products` and `users` tables. I'm asking because I believe your relationship methods are poorly written.

Comment: you can see my edition. I have tried to add a second parameter for wherewith product_id but I don`t know how to add this. I have added a second parameter for user_id but for product_id i don't know how to add this ? any suggestions